# Copy contents from one Dataframe to another based on column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Two seperate similar DataFrames with different lengths

`df2`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 25 | Male | 155 |
| 1 | John | 27 | Male | 175 |
| 2 | Patricia | 23 | Female | 135 |
| 3 | Mary | 22 | Female | 125 |
| 4 | Martin | 30 | Male | 185 |
| 5 | Margaret | 29 | Female | 141 |
| 6 | Kevin | 22 | Male | 198 |

`df1`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 25 | Male | 165 | 5'10 |
| 1 | John | 27 | Male | 175 | 5'9 |
| 2 | Matthew | 29 | Male | 183 | 6'0 |
| 3 | Patricia | 23 | Female | 135 | 5'3 |
| 4 | Mary | 22 | Female | 125 | 5'4 |
| 5 | Rachel | 29 | Female | 123 | 5'3 |
| 6 | Jose | 20 | Male | 175 | 5'11 |
| 7 | Kevin | 22 | Male | 192 | 6'2 |

`df2` has some rows which are not in `df1` and `df1` has some values which are not in `df2`.

I am comparing `df1` against `df2`. I have calculated the `newentries` with the following code

```
newentries = df2.loc[~df2['First Name'].isin(df1['First Name'])]
deletedentries = df1.loc[~df1['First Name'].isin(df2['First Name'])]
```

where `newentries` denote the rows/entries that are there in `df2` but not in `df1`; `deletedentries` denote the rows/entries that are there in `df1` but not in `df2`. The above code works perfectly fine.

I need to copy the height from `df1` to `df2` when the first names are equal.

```
df2.loc[df2['First Name'].isin(df1['First Name']),"Height"] = df1.loc[df1['First Name'].isin(df2['First Name']),"Height"]
```

The above code copies the values however indexing is causing an issue and the values are not copied to the corresponding rows, I tried to promote `First Name` as the Index but that doesn't solve the issue. Please help me with a solution

Also, I need to calculate the modified values, if the `First Name` is same, I need to check for modified values; for example in `df1`, the weight of `James` is 155 however in `df2` the weight is 165, so I need to store the modified weight of James(165) and index(0) in a new dataframe without iteration; the iteration takes a long time because this is a sample of a big dataframe with a lot more rows and columns.

Desired output:

`df2`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James | 25 | Male | 155 | 5'10 |
| 1 | John | 27 | Male | 175 | 5'9 |
| 2 | Patricia | 23 | Female | 135 | 5'3 |
| 3 | Mary | 22 | Female | 125 | 5'4 |
| 4 | Martin | 30 | Male | 185 |  |
| 5 | Margaret | 29 | Female | 141 |  |
| 6 | Kevin | 22 | Male | 198 | 6'2 |

`Martin`'s and `Margaret`'s heights are not there in `df1`, so their heights are not updated in `df2`

`newentries`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Martin | 30 | Male | 185 |  |
| 5 | Margaret | 29 | Female | 141 |  |

`deletedentries`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Matthew | 29 | Male | 183 | 6'0 |
| 5 | Rachel | 29 | Male | 123 | 5'3 |
| 6 | Jose | 20 | Male | 175 | 5'11 |

`modval`=

| Index | First Name | Age | Gender | Weight | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | James |  |  | 165 |  |
| 7 | Kevin |  |  | 192 |  |

Comment: could you please also add a desired output for your data ?

Comment: you need to add newline between `newentries` and the actual table to get the right table format displayed. same for `deletedentries`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Rabinzel's answer:

```
output = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='First Name', suffixes=[None, '_old'])
df3 = output[['First Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Weight', 'Height']]

cols = df1.columns[1:-1]
modval = pd.DataFrame()
for col in cols:
    modval = pd.concat([modval, output[['First Name', col + '_old']][output[col] != output[col + '_old']].dropna()])
    modval.rename(columns={col +'_old':col}, inplace=True)

newentries = df2[~df2['First Name'].isin(df1['First Name'])]
deletedentries = df1[~df1['First Name'].isin(df2['First Name'])]

print(df3, newentries, deletedentries, modval, sep='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
  First Name  Age  Gender  Weight Height
0      James   25    Male     155   5'10
1       John   27    Male     175    5'9
2   Patricia   23  Female     135    5'3
3       Mary   22  Female     125    5'4
4     Martin   30    Male     185    NaN
5   Margaret   29  Female     141    NaN
6      Kevin   22    Male     198    6'2

  First Name  Age  Gender  Weight
4     Martin   30    Male     185
5   Margaret   29  Female     141

  First Name  Age Gender  Weight Height
2    Matthew   29   Male     183    6'0
5     Rachel   29   Male     123    5'3
6       Jose   20   Male     175   5'11

  First Name  Age Gender  Weight
0      James  NaN    NaN   165.0
6      Kevin  NaN    NaN   192.0
```

Comment: `First Name_old` is created in the very first line, if you've modified your inputs or my code, not sure what to tell you.

Comment: On a larger DataFrame with lot more rows and columns, the concat function is wrongly adding equal values as not equal

Answer (score 1):

for your desired output for `df2` you can try this:

```
desired_df2 = df2.merge(df1[['First Name','Height']], on='First Name', how='left')
#if you want to change the "NaN" values just add ".fillna(fill_value=0)" for e.g 0 after the merge
print(desired_df2)


  First Name  Age   Gender  Weight Height
0     James    25    Male      155   5'10
1      John    27    Male      175    5'9
2  Patricia    23  Female      135    5'3
3      Mary    22  Female      125    5'4
4    Martin    30    Male      185    NaN
5  Margaret    29  Female      141    NaN
6     Kevin    22    Male      198    6'2
```

new and deleted entries is already right. for the moment I'm a bit stuck how to get the modval dataframe. I'll update my answer if I get a solution.